# updating collection with mongoose after an aggregation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I'm currently working for a small firm as an intern and I'm working on **user** schema that goes like this :

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true
    },
    username: {
        type: String,
        unique: true
    },
    hashed_password: String,
    provider: String,
    salt: String,
```

and due to changes on the app I work on, I update this schema in that :

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true
    },
    username: {
        type: String,
        unique: true
    },
    hashed_password: String,
    provider: String,
    salt: String,


    stats : {
        bricks: Number,// Number of bricks created by an user
        layers: Number,// --------- layers ------------------
        projects: Number,//-------- projects ----------------
        lastogin: Date
    },

});
```

Of course, there is a former version of the app online, and I need to update all users existing in the user collection.

For that, I need to count every bricks/layers/projects created by every users. this the **brick** schema:

```
/**************
App fields
**************/

// False deletion field
field.deleted = function() {
  return field.bool();
};

// Creation date
field.created = function() {
  return field.date();
};

// Title Field
field.title = function() {
  return field.string();
};

// Desc Field
field.desc = function() {
  return field.string();
};

// Default short Id field
field.shortId = function(id) {
  return {
    type: ShortId,
    index: true,
    len: 7,     // Length 7 characters
    base: 64,   // Web-safe base 64 encoded string
    alphabet: "abcdefghijklmnopkrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890", // Use default alphabet for base
    retries: 4  // Four retries on collision
  };
};

// The author of the content
field.user = function() {
  return {
    user: field.ref('User'),
  }
};

field.favorites = function() {
  return [{
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  }];
};

field.contributors = function() {
  return [{
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  }];
};

field.comments = function() {
  return [{
    // user that have written the comment
    user: field.ref('User'),
    // comment text it-self
    comment: field.string()
  }];
};
```

After some research I decided to use the aggregation pipeline of mongoose (and mongodb) to group bricks by users using, the following query :

```
db.bricks.aggregate(
    [
        {
            $group : {
                _id : "$user",
                count : {  $sum : 1}
        }
    ]
)
```

and the following methods with **mongoose** :

```
var promise =Brick.aggregate()
        .group({ _id: "$user"})
        .exec(function (err, res) {
            if (err) return handleError(err);
            else {
                console.log(res);
            }
        });
```

I know that the exec() methods returns a [promise](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#aggregate_Aggregate-exec) and I'm still learning about using it correctly.

After that I would like  to execute an update query on all the users. As they didn't created the same number of bricks, I can't make a multi update and I need to loop to through the results with a query which make look like this :

```
User.update({id : user_id}, {$set : {"stats.bricks" : Brick.find({user : user_id}).count()}})
```

Is it possible to do it this way or do I need to rethink the problem in a different way

Comment: You're close, but unfortunately `.exec()` does not return a promise. Omit the `.exec()` and you actually have a promise from which you can act on the results. Oh and that last code example is obviously borrowed from the MongoDB shell, where what you "think" is happening is not what is really happening. As a "synchronous" process, the inner query results get evaluated before the the outer query is executed. May as well be a static value

Comment: Thanks ! But on the docs of the mongoose API it is written that .exec() return a promise ( the link on the word promise redirect on the API docs ). Anyway, I suspested that the last "query" won't work like this and I added a "count" field to the group (you can see it in the mongoshell query) to get the numbers of elements created by an user and then use it for the update.

Comment: Hmm. Thankyou first poster here ever for actually paying attention to who just gave you good advice ( not! ). No it does not. `.exec()` specifically requires a "callback" as an argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried something else and succeeded to get the result I wanted

```
exports.updatesUsersStats = function (req, res) {
  User.find().exec(function(err, users) {
    console.log(users.length);
    _.each(users, function(currentUser) {
      console.log("Count bricks user :" +currentUser._id);
      Brick.find({user : currentUser._id})
        .exec(function(err, bricks) {
          if(err) return handleError(err);
          console.log("Update user :"+ currentUser._id);
          User.update({_id : currentUser._id}, {$set : {"stats.bricks" : bricks.length}})
            .exec(function(err)
            {
              if(err) return handleError(err);
            });
        });
    });
    res.jsonp({
      updateType : "updateUserStats",
      operations : users.length
    });
  });
};
```

I put aside the aggregation that does take into consideration all the user (whose who didn't create contents).